# Cинтаксический разбор (обособленное определение + обстоятельство)

Tags: синтаксис

*Рвать жертву хищник сразу не станет, а поместит за корягу или в пещеру, вырытую для этого в берегу под водой, и подождет, пока добыча "отмокнет".*

Фраза "вырытую для этого в берегу под водой" полностью будет обособленным определением, или только "вырытую для этого", а остальное будет обстоятельством? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

... в пещеру, вырытую для этого в берегу под водой, ...- обособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом. Это всё - определение, подчёркиваем волнистой чертой,а уж потом, если хотите, можете разобрать по членам оборот: вырытую-определение, для этого - обст. цели, в берегу-обст. с оттенком дополнения(подчёркиваем дважды - и как дополнение, и как обст-во), под водой - обстоят. места.

Answer (score 0):

Одни учебные сайты взирают на причастный оборот в предложении как на обособленное согласованное определение, всё подчеркнутое единой волнистой линией.

А другие дробят на определение и обстоятельства...

Тогда, если разбирать отдельно причастный оборот "вырытую для этого в берегу под водой", в нём обстоятельствами будут:

1) вырытую - где? в чём? - в берегу под водой,
2) вырытую - для чего? с какой целью? - для этого.

Убедитесь (смотрим только на причастный оборот в предложениях, неважно,  что у нас "непростое"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Причастный оборот осложняет предложение только в том случае, если он
>   обособлен. При этом в описании следует указывать на осложнение не
>   причастным оборотом, а обособленным определением; в скобках возможно,
>   но не обязательно указание на то, что оно выражено причастным
>   оборотом.

[ИСТОЧНИК](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/277-sintaksicheskiyrazborprostogopredlogeniya.html)

Нашла пример с деепричастием (что несущественно) - оно тоже рассматривается как единое определение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Нашла пример с деепричастием  - оно тоже рассматривается как единое определение".-Вы хотели сказать: деепричастный оборот рассматривается как  единый член предложения - обстоятельство.

Comment: Мой "пример с деепричастием" подчёркнут как определение.

Comment: У Вас здесь и деепричастный оборот, подчёркнутый как обстоятельство, и причастный - как определение

Comment: Ой-ё!!! Я деепричастие не прочла, вообще не удосужилась прочесть всё написанное, а среагировала на волнистую линию, обозвав причастие деепричастием! Т_Т

Comment: Ну а детям-то как объяснять? Дробить на определения и обстоятельства или не дробить? А объяснение, что одни говорят так, а другие - так, только путаницу создаст в их головах.

Comment: Ириша Робертовна в таких случаях говорит не как объяснять детям, а какая у вас, детки, в вашей конкретной школе, метода преподавания. Об этом можно спросить учителя и  можно блеснуть широтою познаний, мол, одни интернетные (компетентные!) источники разрешают вот это, другие - вот то.